# Syntax error (ClassNotFoundException) compiling at (deps.edn:0:0). JSON Clojure error

Tags: json, clojure, deps-edn

I am trying to use the JSON library on clojure, but I am not able to install it, and I instead get the

```
[org.clojure/data.json "2.4.0"]
Syntax error (ClassNotFoundException) compiling at (REPL:0:0).
org.clojure
```

error message, I am using IntelliJ IDEA and I created a `Deps` project with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSKiV.png) structure, in the `deps.edn` file I have:

```
{:paths ["src"]
 :deps  {org.clojure/spec.alpha {:mvn/version "0.3.218"}}}
 {:deps {org.clojure/test.check {:mvn/version "1.1.0"}}}
 {:deps {org.clojure/data.json {:mvn/version "2.4.0"}}}
```

But when I evaluate the  `{:deps {org.clojure/data.json {:mvn/version "2.4.0"}}}` line in the terminal, I get the error message that I previously showed.

I dont have any plugin or whatever, I write the code on the IDE and then I run the `clojure` command on the terminal and evaluate the code I just wrote. Maybe that is the cause of the issue?

I found [this](https://clojure.org/guides/repl/annex_troubleshooting), [this](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs/issues/177) and [this](https://github.com/cnuernber/libjulia-clj/issues/2) sites but somehow they don't work for me. Thanks if you can help.

Comment: Your `deps.edn` looks like nonsense: why are there three separate `:deps` maps? Find an example of a real project's `deps.edn` and use something similar.

Comment: I find no examples of project's `deps.edn` files for the moment, how exactly should I modify it?

Comment: @CoolTiger, https://github.com/search?q=deps.edn

Comment: I just modified the `deps.edn` file, but same thing is happening

Answer (score 1):

The *deps.edn* file is a *map*, and in a *map*, you can have any number of distinct keys. A *deps.edn* file has a structure as follows:

```
    {:paths ["path1" "path2" ..]
     :deps { deps1
             deps2
             ... }
     :aliases {
       :alias1 {}
       :alise2 {}
       ...
     }
    }
```

And in your case, it will be as follows:

```
 {:paths ["src"]
  :deps  {org.clojure/spec.alpha {:mvn/version "0.3.218"}
          org.clojure/test.check {:mvn/version "1.1.0"}
          org.clojure/data.json {:mvn/version "2.4.0"}}}
```

Comment: I just pasted the 2nd code but I get `Syntax error (ClassNotFoundException) compiling at (REPL:0:0).
org.clojure
#:mvn{:version "2.4.0"}
` error. Basically I am in the same problem as I can't include the library.

Comment: It appears that you are trying to eval the above in the REPL? You are supposed to edit the `deps.edn` file as shown above and then restart your REPL. That will load the needed dependencies.